# How do I connect to the local node run by Mist/Ethereum Wallet 0.9.0 from Web3 JavaScript app API?

Tags: web3js, mist

How do I connect to the local node run by Mist/Ethereum Wallet 0.9.0 from Web3 JavaScript app API?

I see in official site that it suggests using

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

However this call fails because there is nothing running on that port.